# Post issue with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

On a page called test.html I want to retrieve some JSON data from a page called test2.php by jquery ajax.

the following code does not work

test.html:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:"test2.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.b.d);
    }
});
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
    $c= '{"a":{"d":6994,"e":20003,"f":7968,"g":12505,"h":6814},"b":{"d":10623,"e":3404,"f":405,"g":17066,"h":24219}}';
    echo $c;
?>
```

Comment: Please post the result of running test2.php. Does it work?

Comment: Are there are any javascript errors?

Comment: does test2.php have json headers?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` and see what you get in the console

Comment: this code dont show me any results and errors even in console it dont show any error too

Answer (score 0):

Your test2.php does not contain the proper headers.  Add this just after

`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: in my browser code work right but in some browsers it dont work. my browser is chrome and my friend is same too but it dont work in its browser!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a JS debugging tool like [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com)
check if your request returns a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aren't sending any data with the request, you probably don't need to use POST.  You can just GET instead.  There's even a useful shorthand method:

```
$.get("test2.php", function(data) {
    // handle your data here
}, 'json');
```

In `test2.php` you are doing things the hard way.  Instead of trying to build a JSON string, just build the data structure you want to send to the client.  Then encode it with `json_encode()`.  You should send the JSON content-type header, so jQuery knows how to decode the data:

```
$c = array(
    'a'=>array(
        'd' =>6994,
        'e' => 2003,
        'f' => 7968,
     )
    // and so on...
);
header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($c);
```